# JMS Destination creation at deployment with Glassfish 3.0.1

Tags: glassfish, queue, jms

I'm currently trying to 'port' my Java EE 5 Application from Jboss 6 M2 to Glassfish 3.0.1

Jboss used to create my JMS Destination Queues a deployment-time thanks to the -service.xml files. I really liked this feature and I would like to find a way to do the same thing on Glassfish. Is this even possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not *sure* of the exact status with GlassFish 3.0.1 but according to these threads:

- http://markmail.org/thread/cqj56ehulg7qdenp
- http://markmail.org/thread/zs4naxy534ijbpic

creating JMS destinations at deploy time **was** not supported. But these threads are pretty old and things might have changed (see below).

You **can** however declare them in a `sun-resources.xml` file and pass it to the [`asadmin add-resources` command](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/819-3662/add-resources-1?a=view).

That being said, several documents (like [this one](http://wiki.glassfish.java.net/Wiki.jsp?page=WeblogicJMSDescriptor) or [this one](http://wiki.glassfish.java.net/Wiki.jsp?page=Gfv31ConnectorsJDBC)) mention the deployment of *application-scoped-resources* defined in a `sun-resources.xml` bundled in the application (that will become [`glassfish-resources.xml` in GlassFish 3.1](http://wiki.glassfish.java.net/Wiki.jsp?page=GlassFishV3.1DeploymentDocPlan)) as part of the deploy/undeploy of the app but:

- I don't know if this is relevant for 3.0.1.
- I don't know the exact status, especially for JMS resources.
- This would require testing.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the sun-resources.xml file. That's pretty much close to what I was searching for. I will try this way and keep you informed.

Comment: After trying many ways, ear deployment with JMS-destinations creation is indeed not supported. Thanks again for this very accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

With glassfish v4x, Connection factory and destinations(ie queue and topics) can be configured in domain.xml file under glassfish/domains/your-domain-name

### Eg :

```
         <resources>
         <connector-connection-pool resource-adapter-name="jmsra" max-pool-size="250" steady-pool-size="1" name="jms/DurableConnectionFactory-Connection-Pool" description="connection factory for durable subscriptions" connection-definition-name="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory">
       <property name="ClientId" description="MyID" value="MyID"></property>
      </connector-connection-pool>
      <connector-resource pool-name="jms/DurableConnectionFactory-Connection-Pool" description="connection factory for durable subscriptions" jndi-name="jms/DurableConnectionFactory"></connector-resource>
      <admin-object-resource res-adapter="jmsra" description="PhysicalQueue" res-type="javax.jms.Queue" jndi-name="jms/MyQueue">
    <property name="Name" value="PhysicalQueue">
    </property>
    </admin-object-resource>
     </resources>
```

---